# oracle 11g - remove duplicate entries after join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

If you have two tables that you join to gather data, but want to remove duplicates - how is this done?

I have two tables; Student and Course

A student can take a course more than once, but when asking 'How many students took course 123 in the past year' - you don't want to count that student more than once, even though he may have taken that course multiple times.

Sample code:

```
select student_id
from student_table
join course_table using (student_id)
where course_id = 123 
and date_taken between '01-JAN-14' AND '31-DEC-14'
```

When I run this, I get the some students showing up 2 or 3 times, as they may have taken the course 2 or 3 times within this period of time (failed once or twice and having to retake the course 2 or 3 times).

Also, is there a quick way to sort these by alphabetic order when displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Simply group by `student_id`:

```
 select student_id 
 from student_table  
 join course_table using (student_id) 
 where course_id = 123 and 
 date_taken between '01-JAN-14' AND '31-DEC-14' 
 group by student_id;
```

You can use `order by` to sort:

```
 select student_name, student_id 
 from student_table  
 join course_table using (student_id) 
 where course_id = 123 and 
 date_taken between '01-JAN-14' AND '31-DEC-14' 
 group by student_id
 order by student_name asc;
```

By the way, you probably want to use *real* date and not strings - like you did, for :

```
 select student_name, student_id 
 from student_table  
 join course_table using (student_id) 
 where course_id = 123 and 
 date_taken between TO_DATE('2014/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND 
 TO_DATE('2014/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
 group by student_id
 order by student_name asc;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I also found that distinct works as well.  

select distinct student_id
from student_table join course_table using (student_id)
where course_id = 123 and date_take between '01-JAN-14' AND '31-DEC-14';

Any ideas on why one would use group or distinct?  Is one more flexible than the other?  Or is it just preference?

Comment: Sure thing! for more info in regards: http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/distinct-vs-group

Answer (score 0):

To find all students who took a course (at least once), use `distinct`:

```
select distinct student_table.*
from student_table
join course_table using (student_id)
where course_id = 123 
and date_taken between '01-JAN-14' AND '31-DEC-14'
```

To simply count how many *different* students took a course, use `COUNT(DISTINCT student_id)`:

```
select count(distinct student_id)
from course_table
where course_id = 123
and date_taken between '01-JAN-14' AND '31-DEC-14'
```

Also note how you don't need to join to student table for the count.